# count jsx within map looping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
{items.filter(item => item.status === 'active').map(item =>
    let total_male = item.length + 1;
    <p>Male ({total_male})</p>
    {this.renderData(item)}
    </div>
)}
```

Is above jsx valid? It make sense to me but it has error. I have a json like this

```
[{"name":"james","satus":"active"},{"name":"alice","satus":"deactived"}]
```

I want to count the obj length that has status active.

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this:

```js
var a = [
           {"name":"james","status":"active"},
           {"name":"alice","status":"deactived"}
];

class App extends React.Component { 

    _createList() {
       let count=0, active;
       active = a.filter(item => item.status === 'active');
       count = active.length;
       return active.map(item => <div>
              <p>Male Count: {count}</p>
              {this.renderData(item)}
            </div>
        )
       }
       
       renderData(item){
          return <div>{item.name}</div>
       }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               {this._createList()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id='container'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jsx you provided is not valid because:

- There is `</div>` but no opening tag `<div>`
- The arrow function have have syntax error
- The arrow function have no return statement
- `item` object have no `length` property (from the JSON data you provided). Maybe you intended to use `items.length` instead?

Fix it:

```
{items.filter(item => item.status === 'active').map(item => {
    let total_male = items.length + 1;
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Male ({total_male})</p>
            {this.renderData(item)}
        </div>
    );
})}
```

Comment: I have problem, item.length is undefined, I just realized it's an object, not array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
{items.filter(item => item.status === 'active').map(item =>{
    let total_male = item.length + 1;
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Male ({total_male})</p>
            {this.renderData(item)}
        </div>
        )}
)}
```

You forgot return and closed div.

Comment: I have problem, item.length is undefined, I just realized it's an object, not array.

Comment: If you need obj lenth, you can use `Object.keys` or `Object.values` and use their lenth.

Comment: Just change `item.length` to `Object.keys(item).length`.